# Help identify this sink faucet please and thank you

Tags: faucet

Help identify this sink faucet please and thank you...

[image]

Comment: Is this just a general question or are you trying to repair or replace it?

Comment: If you'd even left the hand-wash bottle the other way round so people might be able to identify even what country, you might have a better chance… though you called it a faucet, so it's maybe US...

Comment: The brand name on the sink looks very unfamiliar to this American, so it may not be US.

Comment: I don't know what brand your faucet is, but I dig your ninja salt & pepper shakers.

Comment: That outlet you can see behind the faucet looks like US. That sink brand is Canadian.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be [Hansgrohe](https://www.hansgrohe-usa.com/kitchen/products/kitchen-faucets?page=2). A close inspection will usually turn up a subtle manufacturer's name etched into the surface.

Comment: Checked and it's not a Vogt.